# Mortgage Balance Calculator in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to be able to take an existing balance for a a mortgage on an account, forecast out what the payments will be over a certain period of time and calculate the balance of the mortgage at a certain period of time. Please note that I am trying to do this within an Oracle SQL environment and I don't have write access in this environment so I cannot create a table as part of the solution.

I found an example of mortgage calculator but I am unsure how I would get this to join to another table with account balances and interest rates to set the starting balance of the calculation and also pull what interest rate should be applied. The following code, forecasts the payments on a mortgage from the current balance of $20,000 to the end of the mortgage is paid off. I then pull out what the balance would be on a particular date (in the below case this is January 1, 2023:

```
select * from
(
select   
  add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MONTH'), rownumber) as date_pmt,   
  to_char(a,'9G999G990D00') balance,   
  to_char(b,'9G999G990D00') interest_pmt,   
  to_char(c,'9G999G990D00') principal_pmt,   
  to_char(d,'9G999G990D00') total_pmt   
from dual  
MODEL   
  DIMENSION BY (rownum rownumber)  
  -- Change Amount, Payment and Interest Rate here!  
  MEASURES (50000 a, 0 b, 0 c, 800 d, 2 e)  
  RULES SEQUENTIAL ORDER ITERATE (500) UNTIL (a[ITERATION_NUMBER + 1] <= 0) (  
    b[ITERATION_NUMBER + 1] = a[cv(rownumber)] * e[cv(rownumber)] / 1200,  
    d[ITERATION_NUMBER + 1] = least(d[cv(rownumber)], a[cv(rownumber)] + b[cv(rownumber)]),  
    c[ITERATION_NUMBER + 1] = d[cv(rownumber)] - b[cv(rownumber)],  
    a[ITERATION_NUMBER + 2] = a[cv(rownumber)-1] - c[cv(rownumber) - 1],  
    e[ITERATION_NUMBER + 2] = e[cv(rownumber)-1],  
    d[ITERATION_NUMBER + 2] = d[cv(rownumber)-1]  
  )  
order by rownumber
)
where date_pmt = '01-JAN-23'
```

This outputs the following:

[image]

I am hoping to also be able to specify the mortgage rate as a field from another table as well. So let's say I have a table like:

What I am hoping to do is take a table that has an account number and current account balance and then feed that account balance into something like the above as the starting point for the mortgage balance (i.e. replace the 20000) and also adjust the interest rate.

Update: I have got the following to a bit better point:

```
WITH mortgage_details (account_id, start_date, balance, annual_interest, pmt, pmt_freq, remain_amort) AS (
  SELECT 1, TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 34798, 2, 670, 'BW', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 50000, 10, 660, 'M', 6 FROM DUAL
),
mtg_final as
(
    select mtg.*,
    case when pmt_freq = 'BW' then 26
         when pmt_freq = 'M' then 12
    end as pmt_freq_updated
    from mortgage_details mtg
)
select * from mtg_final
where account_id = 1  
MODEL   
  DIMENSION BY (rownum rownumber)  
  -- Change Amount, Payment and Interest Rate here!  
  MEASURES (balance, 0 b, 0 c, pmt d, annual_interest e)  
  RULES SEQUENTIAL ORDER ITERATE (500) UNTIL (balance[ITERATION_NUMBER + 1] <= 0) (  
    b[ITERATION_NUMBER + 1] = balance[cv(rownumber)] * e[cv(rownumber)] / 1200,   
    d[ITERATION_NUMBER + 1] = least(d[cv(rownumber)], balance[cv(rownumber)] + b[cv(rownumber)]),  
    c[ITERATION_NUMBER + 1] = d[cv(rownumber)] - b[cv(rownumber)],  
    balance[ITERATION_NUMBER + 2] = balance[cv(rownumber)-1] - c[cv(rownumber) - 1],  
    e[ITERATION_NUMBER + 2] = e[cv(rownumber)-1],  
    d[ITERATION_NUMBER + 2] = d[cv(rownumber)-1]  
  )  
order by rownumber
```

However, when I try to change the hard-coded 1200 to something from the table, I get an error. I tried the following:

```
WITH mortgage_details (account_id, start_date, balance, annual_interest, pmt, pmt_freq, remain_amort) AS (
  SELECT 1, TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 34798, 2, 670, 'BW', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 50000, 10, 660, 'M', 6 FROM DUAL
),
mtg_final as
(
    select mtg.*,
    case when pmt_freq = 'BW' then 26
         when pmt_freq = 'M' then 12
    end as pmt_freq_updated
    from mortgage_details mtg
)
select * from mtg_final
where account_id = 1  
MODEL   
  DIMENSION BY (rownum rownumber)  
  -- Change Amount, Payment and Interest Rate here!  
  MEASURES (balance, 0 b, 0 c, pmt d, annual_interest e)  
  RULES SEQUENTIAL ORDER ITERATE (500) UNTIL (balance[ITERATION_NUMBER + 1] <= 0) (  
    b[ITERATION_NUMBER + 1] = balance[cv(rownumber)] * e[cv(rownumber)] / (100*remain_amort*pmt_freq_updated),  
    d[ITERATION_NUMBER + 1] = least(d[cv(rownumber)], balance[cv(rownumber)] + b[cv(rownumber)]),  
    c[ITERATION_NUMBER + 1] = d[cv(rownumber)] - b[cv(rownumber)],  
    balance[ITERATION_NUMBER + 2] = balance[cv(rownumber)-1] - c[cv(rownumber) - 1],  
    e[ITERATION_NUMBER + 2] = e[cv(rownumber)-1],  
    d[ITERATION_NUMBER + 2] = d[cv(rownumber)-1]  
  )  
order by rownumber
```

And I get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive function to calculate the compound balances for multiple input rows:

```sql
WITH table_name (account_id, start_date, balance, annual_interest, monthly_pmt) AS (
  SELECT 1, TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 50000, 2, 800 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 50000, 10, 0 FROM DUAL
),
calc (
  account_id,
  rn,
  dt,
  balance,
  annual_interest,
  monthly_interest,
  monthly_pmt
) AS (
  SELECT account_id,
         1,
         ADD_MONTHS(start_date, 1),
         balance,
         1 + annual_interest/100,
         POWER(
           1 + annual_interest/100,
           -- days_in_month / days_in_year
           (ADD_MONTHS(start_date, 1) - start_date)
           / (ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(start_date, 'YYYY'), 12) - TRUNC(start_date, 'YYYY'))
         ),
         monthly_pmt
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT account_id,
         rn + 1,
         ADD_MONTHS(dt, 1),
         balance * monthly_interest - monthly_pmt,
         annual_interest,
         POWER(
           annual_interest,
           (ADD_MONTHS(dt, 1) - dt)
           / (ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(dt, 'YYYY'), 12) - TRUNC(dt, 'YYYY'))
         ),
         monthly_pmt
  FROM   calc
  WHERE  rn < 300
  AND    balance * monthly_interest - monthly_pmt > 0
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY account_id SET order_rn
SELECT account_id,
       dt,
       ROUND(balance, 2) AS opening_balance,
       ROUND(balance * (monthly_interest - 1), 2) AS interest_amt,
       ROUND(
         GREATEST(
           LEAST(
             monthly_pmt - balance * (monthly_interest - 1),
             balance
           ),
           0
         ),
         2
       ) AS principal_pmt,
       ROUND(LEAST(monthly_pmt, balance * monthly_interest), 2) AS total_pmt,
       ROUND(
         GREATEST(balance * monthly_interest - monthly_pmt, 0),
         2
       ) AS closing_balance
FROM   calc
```

*Note: your calculation of the interest rate looks wrong as you take your rate and divide by 1200. If you are using daily interest then you should take the `n`<sup>th</sup> root of the annual interest rate, where `n` is the number of days in the year and then for a month you need to raise that daily rate to the power of the number of days in the month. You can check if the calculation is correct by setting the monthly payment to zero and then after 12 months the closing balance should have increased by the annual interest rate.*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=2d0b4944f98118a5cb990d15bb752b5f)*

---

> how would I change this if I payments were weekly or biweekly?

If you want to do two-weekly payments then you may find that you have a range that spans the year-boundary between a leap and a non-leap year so you may have slightly different daily interest rates in those two years and it may be simpler to calculate daily interest and then aggregate into two-weekly periods.

One possible solution is:

```sql
WITH table_name (account_id, start_date, balance, annual_interest, biweekly_pmt) AS (
  SELECT 1, TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 50000,  2, 400 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 50000, 10, 0 FROM DUAL
),
calc (
  account_id,
  rn,
  dt,
  balance,
  annual_interest,
  daily_interest,
  biweekly_pmt,
  payment
) AS (
  SELECT account_id,
         1,
         start_date + INTERVAL '1' DAY,
         balance,
         1 + annual_interest/100,
         POWER(
           1 + annual_interest/100,
           1 / (ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(start_date, 'YYYY'), 12) - TRUNC(start_date, 'YYYY'))
         ),
         biweekly_pmt,
         0
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT account_id,
         rn + 1,
         dt + INTERVAL '1' DAY,
         balance * daily_interest - payment,
         annual_interest,
         POWER(
           annual_interest,
           1 / (ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(dt, 'YYYY'), 12) - TRUNC(dt, 'YYYY'))
         ),
         biweekly_pmt,
         CASE MOD(rn + 1, 14) WHEN 0 THEN biweekly_pmt ELSE 0 END
  FROM   calc
  WHERE  rn < 9000
  AND    balance * daily_interest - payment > 0
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY account_id SET order_rn
SELECT account_id,
       dt,
       ROUND(opening_balance, 2) AS opening_balance,
       ROUND(interest_amt, 2) AS interest_amt,
       ROUND(LEAST(payment, opening_balance + interest_amt), 2)
         AS payment,
       ROUND(GREATEST(opening_balance + interest_amt - payment, 0), 2)
         AS closing_balance
FROM   calc
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY account_id
  ORDER     BY rn
  MEASURES
    LAST(dt) AS dt,
    FIRST(balance) AS opening_balance,
    SUM(balance*(daily_interest - 1)) AS interest_amt,
    SUM(payment) AS payment
  PATTERN (days{1,14})
  DEFINE days AS 1 = 1
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=6d108c9a4f27cb4c815b3aa134557be0)*

---

If you want a mix of periods then something like:

```sql
WITH table_name (account_id, start_date, balance, annual_interest, payment, payment_frequency) AS (
  SELECT 1, TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 5000,  2, 100, 'WEEKLY' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 5000,  2, 200, 'TWO-WEEKLY' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 5000,  2, 400, 'MONTHLY' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 5000, 10, 0,   'MONTHLY' FROM DUAL
),
calc (
  account_id,
  rn,
  dt,
  balance,
  annual_interest,
  daily_interest,
  payment_amount,
  payment_frequency,
  payment
) AS (
  SELECT account_id,
         1,
         start_date + INTERVAL '1' DAY,
         balance,
         1 + annual_interest/100,
         POWER(
           1 + annual_interest/100,
           1 / (ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(start_date, 'YYYY'), 12) - TRUNC(start_date, 'YYYY'))
         ),
         payment,
         payment_frequency,
         NULL
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT account_id,
         rn + 1,
         dt + INTERVAL '1' DAY,
         balance * daily_interest - COALESCE(payment, 0),
         annual_interest,
         POWER(
           annual_interest,
           1 / (ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(dt, 'YYYY'), 12) - TRUNC(dt, 'YYYY'))
         ),
         payment_amount,
         payment_frequency,
         CASE
         WHEN (payment_frequency = 'MONTHLY'    AND  dt = LAST_DAY(dt))
         OR   (payment_frequency = 'TWO-WEEKLY' AND  MOD(rn, 14) = 0)
         OR   (payment_frequency = 'WEEKLY'     AND  MOD(rn, 7) = 0)
         THEN payment_amount
         END
  FROM   calc
  WHERE  rn < ROUND(365.25 * 25)
  AND    balance * daily_interest - COALESCE(payment, 0) > 0
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY account_id SET order_rn
SELECT account_id,
       dt,
       ROUND(opening_balance, 2) AS opening_balance,
       ROUND(interest_amt, 2) AS interest_amt,
       ROUND(LEAST(payment, opening_balance + interest_amt), 2)
         AS payment,
       payment_frequency,
       ROUND(GREATEST(opening_balance + interest_amt - payment, 0), 2)
         AS closing_balance
FROM   calc
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY account_id
  ORDER     BY rn
  MEASURES
    LAST(dt) AS dt,
    FIRST(balance) AS opening_balance,
    SUM(balance*(daily_interest - 1)) AS interest_amt,
    SUM(payment) AS payment,
    FIRST(payment_frequency) AS payment_frequency
  PATTERN ( no_payment* has_payment)
  DEFINE
    no_payment  AS payment IS NULL,
    has_payment AS payment IS NOT NULL
)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=308097e7a278c00e9b58892b610b3c73)*

Comment: thanks for this. Just wondering, how would I change this if I payments were weekly or biweekly?

Comment: @jacoby Calculate daily interest and aggregate. Something like [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=6d108c9a4f27cb4c815b3aa134557be0).

Comment: Thanks @MT0. I am thinking what I would like to have is in the "table_name" I might want to specify the payment frequency (i.e. Monthly, Weekly, Biweekly) and then based on that, perform the calculation. Do you think something like that would be possible?

Comment: Something like [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=70e2936c9ec0e168d769cb5943bcad3b)

Comment: Thanks @MT0 - I tried working a bit more with what I started with (see my modified question - second part) - just wondering do you know why I might be getting the error I am getting and if so, is there a way to fix it so that I can pass in remain_amort and pmt_freq_updated to replace the 1200 that I have hardcoded orginally?

Comment: @jacoby You cannot refer to things that are outside the model from inside the model. You need to add `remain_amort` and `pmt_freq_updated` to the `MEASURES` clause.

Comment: thanks for that tip and all your help with this question! I did try adding those to the `MEASURES` clause but still seemed to get that error. Here is my db fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=29be0d191cd598980452ceeef649b7c2 I did find a workaround but just more curious now why this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @jacoby [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=80b219ec7423f6bc22a61e7988c30f06) You were referring to them as `remain_amort` and `pmt_freq_updated` (columns) rather than as `remain_amort[1]` and `pmt_freq_updated[1]` (cells in the model).

Comment: Thanks very much @MT0! I have another question about a way to stop the iteration at the point when the Balance reaches zero, but I can ask that as another question as per another poster's advice.